# ASP.NET MaskedEditExtender & TextBox: Cannot enter zero, workarounds? Solutions?

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to enter a 0 into a Textbox hooked into a MaskedEditExtender. My mask is set for a NUMBER(13,2) with 9999999999999.99 as my Decimal mask.

The problem is that the user HAS to enter a number. The value can be 0. I've tested multiple times trying to try 0 in, and it won't work when entering RightToLeft.

Any workarounds? Solutions?

I tried to OnBlur the Textbox inside my UserControl when the value = my mask, but it won't change my textbox to 0.00. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: Can you post your code so we can see what you're currently doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like this isn't supported: http://forums.asp.net/t/1087548.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. I added a simpe helper function to do this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Generally use this property, if its 0 then user shud not even need to enter anything

> AutoCompleteValue - Default character
>   to use when AutoComplete is enabled