# ASP.NET AJAX ToolKit: Numeric MaskedEditExtender issue 

Tags: asp.net

I have an AJAX ToolKit MaskedEditExtender control:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="payRateTextBox" runat="server" 
    CssClass="valueControl"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="payRateMaskedEditExtender" runat="server" 
    AcceptNegative="Left" InputDirection="RightToLeft" 
    Mask="999.99" MaskType="Number" 
    TargetControlID="payRateTextBox"  />
```

Empty text looks like the following when it gets focus:

> __*_*_.*_*_

The problem is the extender dosent allow user to enter a 0 as the first entered character in the first digit at the left of the point (Where the X resides) ..

> ___*X.*___

[Here](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/maskededit/maskededit.aspx) is a demonstration.

Suggestions are apprectiated ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know I cant earn my own bounty, so, my answer here is just for suggesting a solution for the problem.

**The problem can be solved simply by eliminating the assigning of the `InputDirection` property** !! I guess it is not appropriate to use it while using float point anyway ..

Of course if I knew that at first place I would save a 50 reputations ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue. Unfortunately, it seems it doesn't have any solution yet.

Take a look at these links:

http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/25108

[ASP.NET MaskedEditExtender & TextBox: Cannot enter zero, workarounds? Solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735530/asp-net-maskededitextender-textbox-cannot-enter-zero-workarounds-solutions)

http://forums.asp.net/t/1087548.aspx

Comment: Thank you. That was expected. However, I wont set such an answer as my accepted answer ..

Answer (score 1):

Try put this code in your page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
        Sys.Extended.UI.MaskedEditBehavior.prototype._MoveDecimalPos = 
           function () {
              var e = this.get_element();
              var wrapper = Sys.Extended.UI.TextBoxWrapper.get_Wrapper(e);
              var curpos = this._LogicFirstPos;
              var max = this._LogicLastPos;
              var posDc = -1;
              while (curpos < max) {
                 if (wrapper.get_Value().substring(curpos, curpos + 1) ==
                     this.get_CultureDecimalPlaceholder()) {
                    posDc = curpos + 1;
                    break;
                }
                curpos++;
            }
            if (posDc == -1) {
                return;
            }
            this.setSelectionRange(posDc, posDc);
        };
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It does not work. It fires an exception stating that Sys is not declared !!

Comment: It seems that, you have placed this script before adding the ScriptManager. Please place this script next to script manager or place this in a window.onload/document.ready event.

Comment: Ok, Bharath. Added with no errors. But how to use it? Will it automatically works? That function must not be called on any event?